# How can I automatically pass one file path into cmd at a time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm using a version of [waifu2x](https://github.com/WL-Amigo/waifu2x-converter-cpp) to upscale large amounts of images. The problem is that it does not have a function for passing in a folder or multiple images at a time. To speed up the process I created a batch file that passes in a file name into a command to process it automatically:

```
@echo off
:start
set /p filename=File name:
wx2.exe -i "C:\Users\codyi\Documents\Dolphin Emulator\Dump\Textures\RZDE01\%filename%.png" -m noise_scale --noise_level 2 --scale_ratio 2 -o "C:\Users\codyi\Documents\Dolphin Emulator\Load\Textures\RZDE01\%filename%.png"
goto start
```

Running the above script opens a cmd window that asks me for a file name. It takes that file, processes it, then asks me for another. While this does speed things up, what I need is some way to paste/drag and drop multiple file names, have it take the first file, process it, then take the second file, and process it, so on and so forth.

Comment: dir/b | xargs -n1 wx2.exe -i

Comment: dir/b only lists the filenames contained within a folder. Do you know to take the results of dir/b, and pass them into a command, one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to pass all files from the folder you had originally:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "C:\Users\codyi\Documents\Dolphin Emulator\Dump\Textures\RZDE01\*.png" /b /a-d ') do (
  wx2.exe -i "C:\Users\codyi\Documents\Dolphin Emulator\Dump\Textures\RZDE01\%%a" -m noise_scale --noise_level 2 --scale_ratio 2 -o "C:\Users\codyi\Documents\Dolphin Emulator\Load\Textures\RZDE01\%%a"
)
pause
```

Comment: This works! But in order for it to work, I have to put the other files that are needed to run the program (.dll and the such) inside the folder where the files are being converted. Is there a way to convert the files in a separate folder `C:\Users\codyi\Documents\Dolphin Emulator\Dump\Textures\RZDE01` than from where the program is running `C:\Users\codyi\Downloads\Waifu2x\waifu2x-converter_x64_0719`?

Comment: Try it now - it's modified to operate in the same location as the original.